# Building a gate to fit in a 3/4" door jamb

Tags: hinges, gates

I am building a gate for a friend of mine to block the door pictured below. The problem I have run into is the jamb has only 3/4" to work with before the door stop. Would it be feasible for me to build the gate as pictured and place the hinges and latch above and below the horizontal supports, directly on the vertical 1x6's?

If I placed the hinges on the horizontal support it would not sit flush with the outside of the door frame. If I did it that way I would need to attach some 3/4" wood to the outside of the frame which I would like to avoid if possible.

Thank you,

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

[image: Pic 4]

Comment: A _piano hinge_ along the entire side of the gate ought to work. You could use a _barrel bolt_ installed on top of the gate with the bolt extending into the jamb. That would provide easy access from both sides.

Comment: Just hold the exterior pickets in a little bit to avoid hitting the doorstop. Then your 1x cross piece is flush with the jamb.